# Show there exists a 1-form on $\mathbb{T}^2$ such that $q^*\eta = \omega$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I came across the following bit of a problem while I was preparing for my qualifying exams, and I am a bit curious about how you would go about proving that the $\eta$ given in the second sentence even existed.

> Let $q:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$ be the quotient map and consider the 1-form $\omega = 2\cos(\pi x)^2 dx + dy$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. *Then $\omega$ descends to a 1-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$ (i.e. there exists a 1-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$ such that $q^*\eta = \omega$).*

You could try to compute something directly, but I don't really have an idea of how you would go about that, and I suspect that there is something more fundamental going on there. Specifically, I am trying to use the fact that, as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{T}^2$, the map $q$ should act as a local diffeomorphism, but I am unsure how to proceed from there. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated; thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more fundamental thing that's going on here is the study of the map $p^* : \Omega^k(M/G)\to \Omega^k(M)$ where $M$ is a manifold, $k$ is some integer and $G$ is a Lie group acting nicely on $M$.

Precisely, $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $M$ so that the quotient $M/G$ really is a manifold etc.

A thing one notices quite easily is that if $\omega\in \Omega^k(M/G)$, then $p^*\omega$ is $G$-invariant : $g^*p^*\omega = p^*\omega$. This is really easy to prove.

The interesting part is the converse : it's not always true, but sometimes it is.

In particular when $G$ is discrete the converse *is true* : any $G$-invariant $k$-form is of the form $p^*\omega$ for some $\omega$ (in fact you can show, with no discreteness hypothesis, that $p^*$ is injective, so $\omega$ is unique).

Here this is your situation with $\mathbb Z^2= G, M= \mathbb R^2$ and the translation action.

You should definitely try to solve this exercise for yourself. If you don't manage, I wrote a solution for $M=\mathbb R, G=\mathbb Z$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840494/differential-forms-on-the-circle-mathbbr-mathbbz/2840571#2840571), and the general proof is essentially the same.

Comment: Oh wow, that's really cool! I didn't think to consider the fact that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a Lie Group! Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem ! In fact (although my differential geometry goes back too long ago for me to know this precisely) you can also characterize the image of $p^*$ when $G$ is not discrete but it's more subtle (I think the fibers of $p$ play more of a role)

Answer (score 0):

I would write $\eta=2\cos(\pi u)^2du+dv$, where $u,v$ are the coordinates on $\Bbb T^2$ induced by $q$ and the standard coordinate system on $\Bbb R^2$. I'm not sure there is much to calculate here. Of course, you have to make sure that this is well-defined as $u,v$ are multivalued, but that's not much work.